# WordPress plugin disappeared?

Tags: wordpress

On my website i have the Revolution Slider plugin installed.

Went to the website today and all you see is the Revolution Slider shortcode and the plugin has vanished. WordPress doesn't update itself automatically, and i haven't installed anything new. The only thing i've changed is some CSS. What could be the problem that suddenly a plugin disappears? There is no Revolution Slider option on the side menu, not even on the plugin list.  I'm baffled.  I've asked my colleagues and they haven't changed anything.

How do i inspect previous changes made to WordPress so i can track what happened?  The slider was working yesterday but not today, now not even in the plugin list.

Comment: I'm sure it's related with this: http://wptavern.com/critical-security-vulnerability-found-in-wordpress-slider-revolution-plugin-immediate-update-advised

Comment: Thanks! I've read the article but does this explain why the revslider plugin is missing?  The theme(Shoptan) i'm using has been discontinued.

Comment: Has your license expired?